# Historical Economic Release Calendar

Tags: data, quant-trading-strategies, backtesting

Does anyone know if any providers have a historical economic release calendar? For example, releases of things like ADP private employment, or ISM surveys? I ask because I would like to backtest a strategy that uses these numbers, but would want to obviously avoid lookahead bias and not use a data-series prior to its release. I have the release data itself, but unfortunately it is labeled as `YYYY-MM` (for example for monthly releases), with no reference as to the actual day of release.

I am willing to pay a small amount if needed - I understand this is not "traditional" data by most means.

Comment: Have you checked www.briefing.com ? They provide the current week's announcements free (which I save to a file) but I assume for a price they can provide the historical file.

Comment: Also, regarding ISM: "The Manufacturing ISM is released on the first business day of the month at 10:00 a.m. (EST). The Services ISM is released on the third business day of the month at 10:00 a.m. (EST)." With this algorithm you can probably generate the dates.

Answer (score 2):

One source is the Federal Reserve Bank of St. Louis (St. Louis Fed) FRED Database:

[FRED Economic Data Releases Calendar: 'https://fred.stlouisfed.org/releases/calendar'](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/releases/calendar)

[ADP Employment: 'https://fred.stlouisfed.org/categories/32250'](https://fred.stlouisfed.org/categories/32250)

Much data can be found here, excepting certain proprietary data such as ISM.